# Elevation interpolation along a (sewer) line

Tags: spatial-analyst, interpolation, 3d-analyst

Here's what I want to do.  I have a vector sewer line feature class that contaings a field for the high invert elevation and one for the low invert elevation.  I can turn them into a raster no problem but what I can't figure out is how to interpolate between the two ends (high and low) and assign the elevations to the raster cells.

Ultimately what I need to do is compare the sewer line raster to an elevation raster to determine likely overflow points in the event of a backed up line.  My thought is it would be similar to creating a reservoir with a blockage being the dam.

I hope I articulated my question sufficently.

Comment: your tags make me "think" ArcGIS is where you are going to do this work. Please articulate program, license level, ver. Also a good answer may need more information about the datatypes, and resolutions.

Comment: Is there a way to identify which end of the line is high and which is low?